# How to query Persian search match from Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, unicode, utf-8, persian

I'm usig Oracle 11g to result based on Persian serach match from DB but result I'm getting is nothing, would you please assist how can I search for a result that part of a field name "address" matched with "تهران", thanks

Below query give me no result!

```
select t1.pname from tableName t1 where t1.address like '%تهران%'
```

Edit:

Type of column address is `varchar2`, my DB characterset is `AL32UTF8`, and I'm on PL/SQL Developer GUI, and running below query gives me `%?????%` as result.

```
select '%تهران%' as a from dual;
```

I tried the same in SQL*Plus, but no luck and same empty result.

Comment: And you can see a row with that value if you query without the filter? Does your client character set (e.g. from NLS_LANG if this is in SQL\*Plus) support those characters properly? What is the database character set, and is the column `varchar2` or `nvarchar2`?

Comment: Do you get anything from `select '%تهران%' as a from dual;`?

Comment: Seems like what you're doing ought to work. Can you try running the same thing though SQL\*Plus? I suppose it's possible PL/SQL Developer is confused, though that seems unlikely. Maybe check its settings to see if it's specifying a character set.

Comment: @AlexPoole, updated Q, in SQL*Plus I got same empty result, even I tried to find for only one character like `ا` in Persian but no resul :'( Do you suggest I re-build a new table from my Original table and change the type to `nvarchar2`? If I do this I can get my desired result?

Comment: No. Hard to tell what's happening. Check your NLS_LANG, and try using `dump()` to check the values in your table are what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so that I founded that Oracle has [`UNISTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions204.htm) function that it ...

> ... takes as its argument a text literal or an expression that resolves to
>   character data and returns it in the national character set. The
>   national character set of the database can be either AL16UTF16 or
>   UTF8. `UNISTR` provides support for Unicode string literals by letting
>   you specify the Unicode encoding value of characters in the string. ...

and I did use `UNISTR` function as following after I extracted my keyword's encoding that I should search for it in [Unicode code converter](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion):

```sql
SELECT t1.pname FROM tableName t1 WHERE t1.address
    LIKE (SELECT UNISTR('%\062A\0647\0631\0627\0646%') FROM DUAL);
```

note that `%`s above are actual literal `%` added to match keyword like in `'%تهران%'` mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.pname from tableName t1 where t1.address like n'%تهران%'
```

just add `n` before `''`